# Inline textOutput in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm relatively new to making Shiny Apps. I encountered a problem that I tried to simplify the relevant part the most. Basically, I want to have an output text inside a fixed text. This is what the simplified version looks like:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput(inputId = "value", label = "Input your number here", min = 0, max =  30, step = 1, value = 16),
  p("Your result is ", textOutput(outputId = "result"), ".")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$result <- renderText({
    if(input$value >= 15)
      return("good")
    else
      return("bad")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

You can see that the text is supposed to have "good" as an output if the slider is on 15 or more. However, instead of doing this, like I want it to: `Your result is good.` It does this:

```
Your result is

good
.
```

It doesn't seem to matter whether `textOutput` is inside a `p()` tag or not. `paste0()` and `paste` only seems to make it worse:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput(inputId = "value", label = "Input your number here", min = 0, max =  30, step = 1, value = 16),
  p(paste("Your result is ", textOutput(outputId = "result"), "."))
)
```

gives

```
Your result is <div id="result" class="shiny-text-output"></div> .
```

It's in a single line, but *really* isn't what I want.

I don't know if there's a way to make this work without writing the whole sentence inside the `renderText` function. It's doable, but I feel there should be a way to do this without repeating the rest of the sentence. I understand if there isn't, though. But then, I'd like to know *why*...

---

After writing this, I realised I could do this on the server side instead:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput(inputId = "value", label = "Input your number here", min = 0, max =  30, step = 1, value = 16),
  p(textOutput(outputId = "result"))
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$result <- renderText({
    if(input$value >= 15)
      text <- "good"
    else
      text <- "bad"
    
    paste0("Your data is ", text, ".")
  })
}
```

It worked: `Your data is good.`. But I still don't get why it doesn't work if I do it in the ui... Is it possible and I'm just not doing something or is that just how it works? Why? I don't get it... Why would it skip to lines, write the output, and the continue the next line?

By now, my question is more about understanding how and why it (doesn't) work than an actual problem, but I work best when I know what I'm doing, so I still think it's a valid question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding `inline=T` removes the line breaks

```
p("Your result is", textOutput(outputId = "result"), ".") ## old 
p("Your result is", textOutput(outputId = "result", inline = TRUE), ".") ## new
```

That gives

```
Your result is good .
```

From the [help file](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.3.2/textOutput.html), `inline` controls whether `span` or `div` is used

```
inline       use an inline (span()) or block container (div()) for the output
```

There is a space before the period and I can't currently figure out how to remove it. But figured I'd post this anyway since it's part of the way there, and maybe you do know how to remove that.

Full code

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput(inputId = "value", label = "Input your number here", min = 0, max =  30, step = 1, value = 16),
  p("Your result is", textOutput(outputId = "result", inline = TRUE), ".")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$result <- renderText({
    if(input$value >= 15)
      return("good")
    else
      return("bad")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Yes, I've seen that the space is there using em() and strong(), too. I think it's something happens when there's a continuity in text... Maybe it's assumed they're different parts of the sentence, and the space is added.